# Is there simpler way to check the Borders.ColorIndex of a range?

Tags: excel, vba

As the title suggests. I know I can loop through all the cells within certain range to check the colorindex of each cell's borders, though I wonder if there's any simpler way to do the same task.

Any insight would be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cell In rng
        Debug.Print cell.Borders.ColorIndex
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP says he is looking for a way avoiding a loop. "I know I can loop".